# Is is possible to use joomla 3 modules on joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

Is there any way to use Joomla! 3 extensions on J!2.5 ?

I need to use Noo Timeline on Joomla! 2.5 but there is no version for it.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/calendars-a-events/time/content-date-a-time/25732

Best regards,

Comment: It might be possible, but it really depends on the extension and how it's coded. Have you tried it?

Comment: technically it could work, or could require minor code changes: but you'll have to share your work, tests you ran, errors you recorded, if you want some help

Comment: Just install it and see.  In theory a correctly developed module will need to possibly change classes/ids to Bootstrap style and that's it. But in practice tons of modules have deprecated code.

Comment: i tested on J!2.5 but i got error 500 JHTML not supported , sth like that , actually i don't know hot to change codes ... anyway thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Change below codes in below files

**In modules/mod_noo_timeline/elements/nootimeline.php** Line no: 25

Change

```
JHtml::_('jquery.ui', array('core','sortable'));
```

To:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js");
$document->addScript("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js");
$document->addStyleSheet("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css");
```

**In modules/mod_noo_timeline/mod_noo_timeline.php** Line no: 16

Add below code:

```
$document->addScript("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js");
```

On line no 24

Change below code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

To:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
```

**In modules/mod_noo_timeline/assets/css/style.css** Line no: 45

replace css for class (.noo-tl-item.left):

```
.noo-tl-item.left {
float: left;
width:50%;
}
```

It worked for me.