# How to use joomla3 module on joomla 2.5?

Tags: jquery, joomla, module, joomla2.5

I have a module for joomla 3. I want to use it on joomla 2.5.27.
If I tried to install the module on joomla2 , it will show "JHtml: :jquery not supported. File not found." .

So I look for about the issue on google, 
it support a solution.

CHNAGE
`JHtml::_('jquery.framework');`

TO

```
(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery'))
{
JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc-addScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js');
}
```

it still not work , is any idea for the issue ??
I can provide my module zip file.

Comment: You are missing the arrow mark there in $doc->addscript.

Answer (score 0):

There is little syntax error on your code, please try the below code

```
if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery'))
{
    JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
    $doc->addScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js');
}
```

Please you can also refer this link [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721275/is-is-possible-to-use-joomla-3-modules-on-joomla-2-5?rq=1)